# Anylogic using state charts to travel

Tags: java, anylogic

I am very new to Anylogic, and I want to model this process that doesn't seem too difficult. However, I really have no idea as to how to go about it. I also do not have a background in Java, so the coding bit is new to me as well.

I have the following state chart within an agent called a "picker":

[image: State chart depicting an enter, a state called "getList", another state called "getItem",a branch asking whether all the items were retrieved, and a state called "done"]

I have a list of items in a warehouse in an excel sheet the columns are "Items, x-coordinate, y-coordinate" which is already in the model (roughly 10 rows). I want to pull the x-coordinates and y-coordinates from all the items listed in that excel file in the "getList" state. Next I want the "picker" to travel to each of those locations one-by-one until every item has been picked. The branch is asking "Do you have all the items?" If yes, it will continue to the "done" state.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, just a general comment: being a beginner, you are trying to model the system as it really is and now you struggle because you try to achieve 10 things at the same time. I suggest you try to start simple. First, get your agent to move to a position. next, define the position from the dbase. Next, repeat it for several tasks... Along the way, you will have *specific* questions that can be answered easily. Your question is a "how do I achieve this model" question, which is really not suitable for SOF (and a lot of work to answer). Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also, there are various example models where agents do similar things, understand those first. For example the wind turbine tutorial but several more :-)

Comment: @Benjamin Hi I appreciate the tips. I'll try to break it down and see if that helps simplify the problem.

Comment: In general, note that this problem is best represented using the Process Modeling library (i.e., a DES model), not agents with statecharts, and it is not a *super* straightforward model. (It is possible to use statecharts to 'drive the flow in a process model' (using Enter and Exit blocks) but that is pretty advanced and only used for particular reasons.)